# Trying to copy cells from column F if column E changes, only if column F > 0

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using a macro assigned to Sheet1 to try and create a Macro that will copy the values in Column F if Column E changes to a certain value, by row specifically. The code debugs fine but doesn't seem to execute on a Worksheet_Change.

Background: Also have macros set to run on open and close of workbook that list the current time ever 3 minutes in a particular cell. This current time is used to find out how long any given employee has been on the clock, given their start time. I want to copy their calculated time on the clock at the greatest point per person and actively sum that at any given moment for my supervisors.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E3:E75")) Is Nothing Then

Dim Rng As Range

Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F3:F75")
For Each cell In Rng
If cell.Value > 0 Then
    cell.Copy
Rng("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
Next cell

End If

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

I don't have an output, nothing is pasted into column J

Comment: Rng("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial it makes no sense. Maybe change Rng to Range. And "J" into "F"? You haven't menton what column J contains

Comment: Put a "stop" after your Intersect line, change a cell in the sheet, then hit F8 to step through your code...you will catch an Invalid procedure call on your line after cell.Copy. Rafal is correct...that line is problematic.

Comment: If you want a value to appear in the next available cell below a range, I typically use `Range("A" & Range("A###").End(xlUp).Row + 1)` where ### is some row number below your dataset. There are more elegant ways to do this, but this is easy.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, I'm not a "developer" by any meaning of the word so I'm just doing what I can.

I've copied a link to the excel file below just so you guys can see what i'm working with. I can change the Rng to Range, and F is meant to be the column where the results will be pasted. However the code currently compiles so I didn't run into any issues like that. Will post back when I try these comments out. Thanks again!

https://xpologistics-my.sharepoint.com/personal/stephen_leu_xpo_com/Documents/TimeBeforeOTCalculator.xlsm?web=1

Comment: Thanks @RafałB.! Just changing the Rng to Range made it paste the value in G to J, which is what I wanted. However its choosing the row to paste it to in that column seemingly at random. Do I just need to remove the End(x1Up).Offset(1) for that to paste with rows.count?